# porting Python 2 syntax to Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I'm trying to run the following code in python3, but it has been written for I'm pretty sure python2:

```
f = open(filename, 'r')
self.lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
if self.lines[-1] != "\n" :
    self.lines.append("\n")
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
  File "randline.py", line 32
    if self.lines[-1] != "\n" :
                              ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Can you help me figure out the correct syntax?

Comment: use _show whitespace_ in your editor.

Comment: remove **all** tabs. Use 4 spaces

Comment: thanks that fixed my problem. add your comment as an answer so I upvote and accept! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 2 allows you to mix spaces and tabs. so you can have indentation like:

```
def foo():
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ]for each in range(5):
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ][space][space]print(each)
[space][space][space][space][space][space][space][space]print("Done!")
```

Line 2 and line 4 will in Python 2 have the same indentation level, but line 2 will do it with a tab, and line 4 will do it with spaces. Printed to the console, it will look like this:

```
def foo()
        for each in range(5):
          print(5)
        print("Done!")
```

But most editors allow you to set how many spaces a tab should be. Set it to four, and you get this:

```
def foo()
    for each in range(5):
      print(5)
        print("Done!")
```

The indentation is still the same, but now it *looks like the indentation is wrong*!

Python 3 therefore do not allow the same indentation level (ie line 2 and 4) to be indented in different ways. You can still mix tabs and spaces, but not in the same indentation level.  This means that

```
def foo():
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ]for each in range(5):
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ][space][space]print(each)
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ]print("Done!")
```

will work, and so will

```
def foo():
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ]for each in range(5):
[space][space][space][space][space][space][space][space][space][space]print(each)
[this is a tab it counts like eight spaces             ]print("Done!")
```

The only way to make that the only way you can make the indentation look weird is of you set a tab to be *more* than eight spaces, and then the indentation not only looks obviously incorrect, you'll notice that a tab will indent 12 spaces (in the below example) so you realize you insert a tab, and not four spaces.

```
def foo():
            for each in range(5):
          print(each)
            print("Done!")
```

Of course, the solution to all your problems is as written in the comments, to never use tabs. I'm not sure why Python 3 still allows tabs at all, there is no good reason for that, really.

Comment: Great article, until the last (troll bait) clause. There are lots of good reasons for tabs, such as coding in proportional width fonts, or consistency with other language, or having a single character map to a construct, or easier editing in editors that don't honor `four spaces as indent` as a single construct. There are other reasons too, which is why the subject was contentious for so long, and why I still code in tabs even though I acknowledge that ship has sailed for Python.

Comment: Also, today I learned that Python 3 does allow mixing of tabs and spaces within a file, just disallows mixing within a given block (as you stated correctly).